# Flask error : AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'

Tags: python, rest, flask, flask-restful, flask-login

I am using Flask to develop restful API. I am writing pytest cases to test the /api/users path.  While testing I am getting below error. 
I am using SQL Alchemy. I am relatively new to Flask. Any help will be highly appreciated

Flask API:

```
@app.route('/api/users', methods=['POST'])
def new_user():
    username = request.json.get('username')
    password = request.json.get('password')
    user = User(username = username)
    user.hash_password(password)
    db.session.add(user)
    db.session.commit()
    return ("user")
```

Pytest case:

```
@pytest.fixture
def client():
    db_fd, app.config['DATABASE'] = tempfile.mkstemp()
    app.config['TESTING'] = True
    client = app.test_client()

    yield client

    os.close(db_fd)
    os.unlink(app.config['DATABASE'])

@pytest.fixture
def user():
    return {
    'username': 'test_username',
    'password': 'test_password',
    'email': 'test_email'
    }



def _new_user(client, user):
    return client.post('/api/users', json.dumps(user))


# REGISTER USER
def test_new_user(client, user):
    res = _new_user(client, user)

    assert res.status_code == 201
    assert 'user' in json.loads(res.get_data())
```

When I run the test case then I get below error

```
    @app.route('/api/users', methods=['POST'])
    def new_user():
>       username = request.json.get('username')
E       AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'

apa/routes.py:20: AttributeError
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is how you're posting the json. You need to modify this line:

```
def _new_user(client, user):
    return client.post('/api/users', json.dumps(user))
```

to be:

```
def _new_user(client, user):
    return client.post('/api/users', json=json.dumps(user))
```

If you don't specify json as an argument, it gets put into the `request.data` attribute rather than `request.json.`

In general, if you're trying to get keys from json posted to an API, it's a good idea to wrap in a try/except since you'll get a server 500 error if the key doesn't exist or no json was posted. With web APIs, it's desirable to be able to return a response to the client even if the post was malformed, which helps with more complicated APIs and debugging.

Answer (score 2):

**I think you should use this method.**

```py
request.get_json()
```

**See this for more details [request.get_json](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/#flask.Request.get_json)**

Comment: Okie. the API works fine when I use Postman to test it.Still I should use request.get_json()?

Comment: Yeah, Try to use : `try: username = request.json_get('username') except: #other stuff`

Comment: I fixed it using request.get_json().get('username'). But still the same issue. 
    @app.route('/api/users', methods=['POST'])
    def new_user():
>       username = request.get_json().get('username')
E       AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'

apa/routes.py:22: AttributeError